# Codeception: testing app based on Yii2 with fixtures causes "too many connections" error

Tags: yii2, codeception, fixtures

Following example shows how I load and unload fixture in any methods which need it:

```
class ServiceTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{

    protected $tester;

    protected function loadFixture()
    {
        $this->tester->haveFixtures(['user' => ['class' => UserFixture::class]]);
    }

    protected function unLoadFixture()
    {
        $this->tester->grabFixture('user')->db->close();
    }

    public function testSuccessSignin()
    {
        $this->loadFixture();
        $form   = new SigninForm([
            'email'    => 'brady.renner@rutherford.com',
            'password' => '123456',
        ]);
        $result = Service::signin($form, new \yii\web\User([
            'identityClass' => Identity::class,
        ]));
        $this->assertTrue($result);
        $this->unLoadFixture();
    }
}
```

But seems `db->close()` not works properly and `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows many connections in "Sleep" status when I run a test looking like above.
Same happens when I load fixture by `_before()` or `fixture()` method (these methods are the unnecessary cause, not all methods need the fixture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `attribute` persistent connection `true` for your database connection, see the issue here non [**`GITHUB`**](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1363)

```
'db' => array(
      'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
      'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2_advanced_test',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'tablePrefix' => '',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
      'attributes'=>[
           PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
      ]
 ),
```

### `EDIT`

Apart from the above given solution if it does not work for you, you can try `@Mik` suggestion in comments, setting `cleanup:false` under yii2 module settings in the codeception Suit configurations see [**`here`**](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3696#issuecomment-258984183)

Comment: This way did'nt work in my case but I found a good tip: to add in codeception Yii module config a string `cleanup: false`. It works properly now https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3696#issuecomment-258984183

Comment: @Mik i appreciate the accept thou glad you found the fix